# dynamic dropdown for file selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to tweak an existing .html file to add a feature. I am very new to the frontend dev env.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input type="button" name="Load" value="Load" onclick="fileLoad();"/>
    <input type="button" name="showFiles" value="Select File" onclick="selectFiles();"/>
</form>
```

I would like to have a dropdown (dynamic list). Which occurs when i click the button `"Select File"`. I have tried to use the `selectFiles()` function to achieve this. Eventhough, I can get the list of files from backend. How can i display it on the frontend

Answer (score 2):

Once you get your list from the server you can do,

```
function makeList(fileNames) {
    // create a container for the select in your html
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");  
    // Create and append select list
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "filesSelect";
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

    // Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = fileNames[i]; // this will depend on the datastructure of your list items
        option.text = fileNames[i]; // this will depend on the datastructure of your list items
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

This function should go as a callback to your server call.

I have not tested it, but it should give you a clear idea.